# How do I view Serial Output on an Android Device?

Tags: android

Within the Arduino IDE Serial.* output can be viewed with Tools / Serial Monitor.  How can I view Serial.* output on an Android?  As a concrete example, how can I view the output from Examples / Communication / ASCIITable?

Comment: This of course depends on the specific Arduino model generation or USB serial cable utilized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These steps will allow your Android device to function as an Arduino Terminal.

- Download a Serial Terminal app.  I'm using [Android Hyperterminal, English version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.passiontech.support.en).
- Attach an OTG ("On The Go") cable to your Android device.
- Attach your Arduino to the OTG using your regular USB cable.
- Make sure the terminal program is set to the same baud rate as your sketch.
- Run the terminal App and select the USB port.

Comment: I didn't find that app, and ended up installing "Serial USB Terminal" by Kai Morich, it works well so far!